# service worker registered when serving locally, but doesn't work online

Tags: javascript, vue.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I built a PWA with Vue, and for some reason when I try and deploy it online, I get this error message in the console:

```
service-worker.js:168 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request for https://example.com/dist/service-worker.js?_sw-precache=935625ad5331efd775a1f6b37f06e3e3 returned a response with status 404
    at https://example.com/service-worker.js:168:25
    at async Promise.all (index 1)
```

I'm thinking that the problem is that `service-worker.js` is being fetched from example.com/dist/service-worker.js, which *does* throw a 404 error when I try to access it. The right path is example.com/service-worker.js.

I am using render.com for my hosting and I've set the Publish Directory to /dist, since that's where the built files are outputted.

[image: render.com Publish Directory]

This is the content of `registerServiceWorker.js`:

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.'
      )
    },
    registered() {
      console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
    },
    cached() {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updatefound() {
      console.log('New content is downloading.')
    },
    updated() {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
    },
    offline() {
      console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    }
  })
}
```

When I build and serve the app locally, it works fine, and I can install it without any problems. I don't know how I can change things so the service worker is fetched from example.com/service-worker.js instead of example.com/dist/service-worker.js, which is an invalid path.But I'm not an expert on this so I'm not sure if this is even the problem.

I used sw-precache to generate the service worker.

I have looked at other questions with similar titles, but most of the comments or answers say to use HTTPS otherwise it won't work, but I *am* using HTTPS, so they don't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used workbox to generate my service worker and it works fine now.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox

```
// workbox-config.js

module.exports = {
  "globDirectory": "dist/",
  "globPatterns": [
    "**/*.{css,ico,svg,png,xml,html,js,json,txt}"
  ],
  "swDest": "public/sw.js"
};
```

```
// vue.config.js

const {GenerateSW} = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        name: 'Name',
        themeColor: '#fff',
        msTileColor: '#fff',
        appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
        appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black',

        // configure the workbox plugin
        workboxPluginMode: 'GenerateSW',
        workboxOptions: {
            swDest: 'sw.js',
        }
    }
}
```